# How to know mysql Error in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following query in my project,

```
$values = array("test"=>"value")
$this->_db->update("tablename",$values,array('id = ?'=> $data['id'],'wid = ?'=> $data['WId']));
```

If i execute first time i got updated with values, if i did second time, Sql error will be something like "`0 rows affected`" . So here I need to know that exception in zend framwork. Kindly help me

Comment: 0 rows affected is not an error, it just means that nothing was updated.

Comment: 0 rows affected isn't an error, there aren't an rows in that table that match the where clause. To be any more help we're going to need more details

Comment: yes its not an error. I want to know whether rows affected or not ..if not not , i need to show some message in my web page like "No datas are updated". Hope you understand my points

Comment: When your form values and the one in the database has no change PDO doesn't returns success. Its the default behavior. I too at some days back was looking for it :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the comments, I think you need to use:

```
$rowsAffected = $this->_db->update("tablename",$values,array('id = ?'=> $data['id'],'wid = ?'=> $data['WId']));
```

`$rowsAffected` will give you the number of rows affected.  So if its `0`, output your message.

Comment: Yes chris 0 is coming even my query had some error, i dont know 0 means for sql query error or its for "0 rows afected". How could i know ?

Comment: What sort of errors do you mean?  Isn't Zend throwing an exception if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract.update(mixed $table, array $bind, mixed $where)
Updates table rows with specified data based on a WHERE clause.

Parameters:
mixed $table The table to update.
array $bind Column-value pairs.
mixed $where UPDATE WHERE clause(s).

Returns:
int The number of affected rows. 

Throws:
Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception
```